# Method with variable number of objects and a list of other arguments

Tags: python

I want to create a method that accepts a variable number of objects and perform some actions(like calling object methods) based on number of other arguments supplied to the method.

e.g. I have an object X with a method updateTable() which accepts a,b as arguments.

What I want to do is that the common code to update table for different objects is placed under a method say updateAllTables().

Is there way to bundle an object and diferent arguments into a structure and supply to the method that accepts variable number of these structures.

Answer (score 5):

To get a Python function to accept an arbitrary number of arguments, just do this:

```
def my_function(*args, **kwargs):
```

and now `args` will be a list of all the positional arguments passed to that function, and `kwargs` is a dictionary of all the keyword arguments.

Since this is a method, you should probably explicitly accept `self` outside of the arbitrary args:

```
def my_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
```

Comment: How will it work for different argument values say a=1, b=2 for Obj1 and a=5, b=6 for Obj2. Here, named arguments don't have same values for all the objects. They are tied closely to the objects.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Just call it with whatever arguments you need.

Answer (score 0):

1. Variable number of arguments can be sent as list of args (usually denoted by) `*args` or as  a key value pairs `**kwargs`. You should note that `**kwargs` should occur after `*args` if you are passing both.
2. You can call a method dynamically using using the following syntax  `getattr(yourobject,'yourfunction')(params,*args,**kwargs)`