# Function call with a variable number of parameters?

Tags: python, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Having more then one parameter with def in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550285/having-more-then-one-parameter-with-def-in-python)

I need to make a function call which will contain a variable number of parameters - The parameters are contained in a list.

It would "look" like this for a list of 2 items:

```
TheFunction(item1, item2)
```

And for a list of 3 items:

```
TheFunction(item1, item2, item3)
```

Is there any easy, pythonic way of doing this? Some kind of loop using `getattr()`, for instance?

The list is of a variable size - I need to be able to call the function with just the list presented as a argument in the code. Specifically, I am calling the client.service.method() function in SUDS to call a web service method. This function accepts a variable number of arguments, I'm simply having trouble with calling it with a variable number of arguments.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826617/method-with-variable-number-of-objects-and-a-list-of-other-arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this,,

`TheFunction(*N_items)`

```
In [88]: def TheFunction(*N_items):
   ....:     print N_items
   ....:

In [89]: TheFunction(1)
(1,)

In [90]: TheFunction(1,2,3)
(1, 2, 3)

In [91]: TheFunction(1,2,3,4,5)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Even for calling `*` will help you...

```
In [92]: l = [1,2,3,4,5]

In [93]: TheFunction(*l)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

In [94]: l = [1,2]

In [95]: TheFunction(*l)
(1, 2)
```

Comment: Thank you! That is close, but not quite what I need (I probably wasn't clear enough in my original question).

The list is of a variable size - I need to be able to call the function with just the list presented as a argument in the code. 

Specifically, I am calling the client.service.method() function in SUDS to call a web service method. This function accepts a variable number of arguments.

Comment: can you be more clear,, it will help you to get appropriate answer

Comment: The answer remains: Call `client.service.method(*mylist)`. My upvote for avasal's answer was before his edit when I thought he meant the calling syntax, not the defining syntax for multiple-argument functions. But they are equivalent.