# Having more than one parameter with def in python

Tags: python, function

So in java you can do something like this if you don't know how many parameters you are going to get

```
private void testMethod(String... testStringArray){

}
```

How can I do something like this in python

as I can't do something like this right?

```
def testMethod(...listA):
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you talking about variable length argument lists? If so, take a look at `*args`, `**kwargs`.

See this [Basic Guide](http://basicpython.com/understanding-arguments-args-and-kwargs-in-python/) and [How to use *args and **kwargs in Python](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/)

Two short examples from [[1]](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/):

Using `*args`:

```
def test_var_args(farg, *args):
    print "formal arg:", farg
    for arg in args:
        print "another arg:", arg

test_var_args(1, "two", 3)
```

Results:

```
formal arg: 1
another arg: two
another arg: 3
```

and using `**kwargs` (keyword arguments):

```
def test_var_kwargs(farg, **kwargs):
    print "formal arg:", farg
    for key in kwargs:
        print "another keyword arg: %s: %s" % (key, kwargs[key])

test_var_kwargs(farg=1, myarg2="two", myarg3=3)
```

Results:

```
formal arg: 1
another keyword arg: myarg2: two
another keyword arg: myarg3: 3
```

Quoting from this SO question [What do *args and **kwargs mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287085/what-does-args-and-kwargs-mean):

> Putting *args and/or **kwargs as the last items in your function
>   definition’s argument list allows that function to accept an arbitrary
>   number of anonymous and/or keyword arguments.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you want:

```
def func(*args):
      # args is a list of all arguments
```

This like a lot of other such information is covered in [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists), which you should read.

Comment: Was just about to edit  my question to ask if I can use that as I saw it around