# Using variables from a returned function as arguments in another function

Tags: python, function, return

I have a function that has 4 parameters defined as:

```
call(a,b,c,d):
```

I have another function called

```
return_args() #that returns 4 variables.
```

When I do the following:

```
call(return_args()) #it errors out saying, that's 1 arguments, not 4 arguments
```

I know I can store the 4 variables in another line previous to the call(), but it it possible to return the variables all within call() line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `*` argument unpacking

```
call(*return_args())
```

This is a shorthand form of the following:

```
a, b, c, d = return_args()
call(a, b, c, d)
```

or even

```
tup = return_args()
call(*tup)
```

Python's `*` operator used in this way essentially says "unpack this tuple and pass the unpacked values to this function as arguments".

The related operator `**` does a similar trick for keyword arguments:

```
def call(arg1=None, arg2=None, **kwargs):
    pass

kwargs = {'arg1': 'test', 'arg3': 'whatever'}
call(**kwargs)
```

`*` and `**` can be used together:

```
def call(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
call(*return_args(), **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `*` operator to send the list as separate arguments:

```
call(*return_args())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the 'variable unpacking' syntax:
`call( *return_args() )`

Alternatively you can use an obsolete syntax: `apply( call, return_args() )`

Answer (score 1):

```
return_args() #that returns 4 variables.
```

This is a misunderstanding, it doesn't return 4 variables. A function like:

```
def return_args():
    return 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Is actually doing this:

```
def return_args():
    mytuple = (1, 2, 3, 4)
    return mytuple
```

and returning a single thing.

Another side of this is "destructuring assignment" in Python, which is the ability to do this:

```
a, b = 1, 2
```

It's a way to assign/bind two variables at once, but it's actually creating then unpacking the sequence `(1,2)`. You can write:

```
a, b, c, d = return_args()
```

and it looks like you returned four things and bound them to four variable names and that's a clean, useful abstraction, but that's not what happened - actually one sequence was created (with 4 things in it), then it was unpacked to match a sequence of variable names.

The two abstractions leak, and you find out that return_args() is returning a single thing when you try to do this:

```
call(return_args()) #it errors out saying, that's 1 arguments, not 4 arguments
```

The other answers are rightly suggesting `call(*return_args())` as one solution, it's documented here under "Unpacking argument lists":  http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

(The other side to this is a function created to accept variable numbers of arguments discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11550319/478656 )